# Java SubImage not fully taking each image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am making a game and I recently brought a sprite sheet with dimensions of 576 × 528. I can not show it or post it on here sadly because it isn't public domain or whatever the legal mumbo jumbo is. But, I am looking to take all the tiny images inside of the image that are 16x16 in each image. The code compiles without any errors, that isn't my problem. My main problem is that when I loop through the "Sprites" array and take each BufferedImage stored in each Tile object and write it into a folder I only get less than half of the images. I went into further debug and found that some of the tiles in the array are null and that is why they are not getting written out, but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
     public class Sprites {
        public SpriteSheet(String path) {

  int cellSize = 16;
  BufferedImage fullSheet = GameUtils.getImg(path);
  sprites = new Tile[(fullSheet.getHeight()/cellSize)*(fullSheet.getWidth()/cellSize)];
  System.out.println(fullSheet.getWidth());
  int r,c;
  BufferedImage img;

  for(r = 0; r < 33; r++)
     for(c = 0; c < 36; c++) {
        img = org.getSubimage(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
        sprites[r*cellSize+c] = new Tile(img);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sprites[r*cellSize+c]` be `sprites[r*36+c]` if you have 36 columns? For clarity in the code, you should probably compute these values (`columnCount` and `rowCount`) and store them in variables. Use them, both when computing the `sprites` array size (`new Tile[rowCount * columnCount]`), when looping (`r < rowCount`, `c < columnCount`) and when computing the `sprites` offset in the loop (ie. `sprites[r*columnCount+c]`).

Comment: Wow thanks, I am just really stupid and didn't even bother to check that